# How do I tell If my strings can be tuned this high?

Tags: electric-guitar, tuning

first of all I’m very new here so please excuse me if I’m doing anything wrong. 
Next of all I’m self learning guitar as a hobby and I’m quite new to that too. I recently bought a distortion pedal and wanting to learn to play a dethklok song but it needs me to tune my guitar to C F A# D# G C. I’m a bit nervous about tuning the 5th string from the top but it’s the furthest I have ever tuned it and I don’t want my strings to break. I believe they are the basic gauges (9-42). So I’m just asking if anyone knows any tips and advice to stop me breaking my strings.
Many thanks,
lolamnma

Comment: If standard tuning is EADGBE, then wouldn't that tuning mean tuning all the strings down a major third, rather than up? Or is the song specifically with a tuning up a minor 6th? I don't play guitar, so sorry if I'm completely missing something.

Comment: @awelotta - with crazy tuning abounding, it *could* go either way! But - I hope you're right, and it's down-tuning. But going that far would need a change of strings to sound sensible. Seems a better option than going up!!

Answer (score 4):

As commented under your question, this would seem like a drop tuning down to the alternate pitches. Tune down to them, not up.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bit of a silly idea. Why do you need to do it? You could just use a capo on a higher fret, and imagine that's the open strings. Or simply play the song with standard tuning - I suppose you're using tab, in which case, it'll still work, but sound low.

There's not ony the high possibility that strings will break, but a more important one that it will put a lot of stress on the guitar, particularly the neck.

Comment: Thinking about it now, and thank you for your advice, I'm just gonna leave it and learn a different song :). Reading everyone's advice I never realized it could damage my guitar neck, not only break my strings.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you'll find out is to try!   And it won't necessarily establish a rule.  Every string breaks eventually.  Got a spare handy?

Comment: Ah I see, that's the problem, I don't have any spares. I'm using Ernie Ball 2723 Cobalt Super Slinky's. I'm debating if I should try it or not.

Comment: Don't debate - just forget the idea! Or be prepared to buy another guitar.

Comment: I don't suppose it would break the GUITAR!